# Positioning two unordered lists one - below-the-other, as a preparation for dropdown navigation

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling really long to position the lists properly. My current code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Option1</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub2</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">Option2</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub5</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">Option3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And style:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#nav {
    display: inline-block;


}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 30px;


}

#nav li {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

    #nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

But now the elements of the sub-list "sink" in the main list. I cannot get rid of that. Any suggestions what to change in the code?

Comment: The indentation of the HTML is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear the final style you're hoping to achieve, but when using relative or absolute positioning you need to be defining margins at the least. Your relative positioning is essentially normal since there's no margin defined. Likewise, your absolute positioning is causing elements to overlap since you haven't given it any margin or padding.

I've commented out the CSS that was causing issues and hopefully this is what you're looking for?

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav {
  display: block;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#nav li {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* float: left; */
  /* position: relative; */
}

#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
}

#nav ul ul {
  /* position: absolute; */
}
```

Comment: This helped a little bit, but this is not what I wanted to achieve. 
I want Option1 Option2 and Option3 be next to each other in the same line, whereas the sub-options are below them.